# Error 404 issues using Struts application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, dmi

I am having some issues running a Struts web app since few days. I tried several solutions from StackOverflow relating to my problem but none of them works.

**web.xml:**

```xml
<display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>

        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <action name="login"
            class="net.viralpatel.struts2.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>

        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**Login.jsp:**

```jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>

<title>Struts 2 - Login Application | ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">

    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />

    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**LoginAction.java:**

```java
package net.viralpatel.struts2;

public class LoginAction {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String execute() {

        if (this.username.equals("admin")
                && this.password.equals("admin123")) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Libs I have added:**

- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- freemarker-2.3.19.jar
- ognl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.15.1.jar

**Error accessing URL:**

`http://localhost:8080/StrutsHelloWorld/`

```
HTTP Status 404 - /StrutsHelloWorld/

type Status report

message /StrutsHelloWorld/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

I tried this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27).

There are no errors on my console, problem view.

Comment: in Netbeans web app errors are displayed not in the 'console' but a separate window for the server .
Does a simple jsp / html-servlet code work ??? (just to check if something is working) . 

secondly once I faced a problem with eclipse IDE that 
          * if I 'run the file' it worked
          * but 'run project' failed (without deploying)

Comment: Consider using maven or similar to manage your dependencies, you're missing several. Check your startup logs.

Comment: https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples - It contains a few maven as well as non-maven netbeans projects, if you require it to start. Please use the latest version of struts2. Your code is `deprecated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 404 means that resource you have requested is not available, the same referred to the action that is didn't map to the request URL.

`FilterDispatcher` is deprecated and may not work with the current Struts version, use `StrutsPrepareAndExcecuteFilter` instead.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in the `struts.xml` add the following

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
   <action name=""><result>/Login.jsp</result></acton>
```

this will forward you to the login page. Also consider to use absolute paths to the JSP resources.

In the JSP use the form that needs to rewrite to

```
<s:form namespace="/" action="login" method="post">

    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />

    <s:submit key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

In the `action` attribute use the action name and provide `namespace` as you did in the package configuration.

Using `method="execute"` is useless in the `s:submit` tag, the method `execute` used by default, and it will not work because you have turned off [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) in the Struts configuration.

*Adding* libraries over the old libraries in the `WEB-INF/lib` doesn't help so much and your application probably would not work, until you *remove and replace* all lower version libraries with higher version and add new libraries needed by the current version of Struts framework.

Comment: Worked fine with  StrutsPrepareAndExcecuteFilter

Answer (score 0):

for me it's I didn't add "lang3" to library, after adding it everything goes well