# Apache Tomcat error : The requested resource is not available

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat, struts2, struts

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_quick_guide.htm) to build my first Struts2 example.

My project name (and war file also) is `HelloWorld` and whenever I try to access
`http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/index.jsp` I get

> The requested resource is not available.

I have my war file in tomcat webapps directory and tomcat is running fine.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 404 issues using Struts application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419661/error-404-issues-using-struts-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is OLD.

It still uses `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` , that is a [deprecated filter since Struts 2.1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103563/1654265).

You need to use the new filter:      `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

Then ensure you have both the filter and the filter-mapping correctly set in your **web.xml**:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils